# Derivation of spectral index in terms slow roll parameters

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

What is the explicit derivation for the relation

$n_s -1 = 2 \eta -6 \epsilon$

where $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ are the first and second potential slow-roll parameters and $n_s$, the spectral index?

All the books I have read give the ad hoc derivation of this result using slow-roll approximated equations $H^2=V/3$ and $3H\dot\phi=-V^{'}$ (taking reduced Planck's mass equal to 1 for ease) in the definition of $n_s$ in terms of differentiation of scalar power spectrum. (See for example D. Langlois' lectures.)